# Records being loaded twice in Entity Framework or only once

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and was looking for some help.

I have the following C# code for my entity data model. My question is: **Will *payables.Vendors* get vendors from the database twice or only once?** These statements actually appear exactly in the same order in my code.  I am not sure if the first call to payables.Vendors will be cached so the second call to payables.Vendors does not go to the database.

```
PayablesEntities payables = new PayablesEntities();

var selectedVendor =(from vendor in payables.Vendors
                     where vendor.VendorID == vendorID
                     select vendor).First();

var pendingVendor = (from vendor in payables.Vendors
                     where vendor.IsPending == true
                     select vendor).First();
```

Comment: @hometoast - The EF version is 4.0.0.0

Comment: v5 supports Object caching, 4.0 does not out of the box. (http://codingatilivedigitally.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/entity-framework-5-0-4-0-performance-improvementspart-3/?relatedposts_hit=1&relatedposts_origin=38&relatedposts_position=0)

Comment: @hometoast, So would v5 automatically cache Vendors objects in my code snippet?

Comment: I wish I had a more specific answer. I only know this because I was considering EF or nhibernate some time ago and ef5 came out with the caching soon after I was done with the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two separate queries then there will be two `SQL` queries to execute.`LINQ to Entities` doesn't magically combine your queries.If you want to execute one query then you need to create one query and combine them.

Comment: I think you did not see my question. All I want to know is if the Vendors are retrieved from database twice?

Comment: @Sunil sorry you right, I have noticed now updated the answer

Comment: I was thinking EF will somehow cache records for a certain period of time, but I guess not.

Comment: @Sunil hmm I don't know much about caching but I don't think the EF will do that automatically.anyway you can use SQL Profiler and experience it yourself, then let us know  :) also this article might be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx